# How can I add internal links to a different section of the same answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, hyperlinks, formatting

Similar to what Wikipedia does, is there a way that I can add *internal* links to my answer?

Comment: There's also a request for this on MSE from 2010: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

For that to work you need to be able to add id attributes to HTML elements and that is prohibited.

[goto section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369074#section)

test

---

The Markdown source of above HTML content looks like this:

```
[goto section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369074#section)

<p id="section">
test
</p>
```

Notice that when rendered, the `<p>` is no longer there.

When you use [disallowed attributes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100) on an HTML tag, the complete tag is removed.